# React states are not being saved to the JavaScript array

Tags: reactjs, state

I am learning about states in React, and below is an exercise to create a to-do list.
I capture the state of each inputted "item" in the to-do list and add them to an "items" array.
Then, each element in the "items" array is rendered using HTML.

I don't understand why I can't just push each item into a normal JavaScript array? After submitting the form, I log the "items" array. However, the "items" array only has 1 element, no matter how many times I submit the form. It seems like previous values are disappearing every time.

I solved the problem by using a React state that is an array. But I still don't understand why I can't use a JS array. Any explanations/resources would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function App() {
  const items = [];

  //const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);

  const [inputText, setInputText] = React.useState("");

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    items.push(inputText);
    console.log(items);

    //setItems((prevValue) => {
    //  return [...prevValue, inputText];
    //});
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setInputText(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="heading">
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
      </div>

      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={inputText} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button type="submit">
          <span>Add</span>
        </button>
      </form>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => {
            return <li>{item}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: have you tried by uncommenting `const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);` ?

Comment: @RGog Sorry I just updated the post, but that was the solution I found. However, I still don't understand why I can't use a Javascript array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69103720/8803194 : this answer is an apt explanation. check this out

Comment: React recreates your component and resets its internal properties on every render.  A component is re-rendered anytime its passed in properties change or its state changes (when you update a `useState` declared value).  To persist data between re-renders you must use `useState`, `useRef`, `useMemo` etc...

Comment: You can use a javascript array but you have to either declare it outside the App component or to memoize it (`const items = React.useMemo(() => { return [] }, []);`), otherwise it will be re-initialized every time the component is re-rendered.

Comment: @Hozeis Got it. Thanks for clearing that up! So everything inside a class or function would be reset on each render (unless I use states)?

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose if its a react class component or functional component, then yes. Also if you want to persist data between multiple components take a look at `context`

Comment: Not everything; the setState functions (e.g. `setItems` and `setInputText`, in your case) are granted to remain the same, even without an explicit memoization. That is why you can safely omit them from the dependencies array `useEffect()`, `useCallback()`, etc. hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `let items = [];` outside the function. Because in react each component reloaded on state update. so it will re-assigned to empty array. Make sure you define it using `let` not `const`

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense! Is there a reason why I should define the array using let instead of const? I thought that it would be fine because I am not reassigning the array.

Comment: It's good. See ```const``` says that you defined it constant you won't change it. Yes you can push but as this is not constant in terms of value let's use let

Comment: @moshfiqrony `const` indicates that the variable will not be re-assigned, not that it is immutable. When the variable holds a primitive value, the two things coincide but with non-primitive values that is not the case. Nonetheless, it is perfectly fine to declare variables holding non-primitive values with `const` and some people might even say it is *advisable* to do so, in order to reduce the risk of unintentionally "overwriting" a variable type as the result of its manipulation

Comment: That make sense @secan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react hook `useCallback` to prevent `items` re-rendering every time state changes `const items = useCallback([], [])`